# Cannot Edit a Content Zone

Tags: 2007

Running MOSS 2007.  Recently, upgraded the servers (WFE & SQL) to 2008 R2.    Additionally, W7 environment with recent upgrade to IE9.

Did not have any issues editing for the first few weeks.  Now, on certain pages (no common master page or layout to pages), when clicking Edit Content, the page freezes.  Eventually, afetr clicking region again, IE9 will say "www is not responding".

One page, there are multiple content regions and web part regions.  You are able to add to add/remove content/webparts from each region, but that one region.  While researching error, (e.g. google) took a stab at one suggestion (remove closed webparts) and deleted 86 closed webparts.  Still no luck.  The other page is a single content region.  The only common thread is the content regions are "Left Content" regions.  I have checked another page and the "Left Content" region works...so far.

I have opened the layouts for the two pages in designer and the code for the content regions look good relative to other content regions that work on the same layouts. I logged onto a 2003 server and used an IE8 browser and encountered the same issue.  Mozilla does not work as well.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW.

Opening in Mozilla while problematic (CAC enabled environment), I was able to get the webpart that was causing the issue.

I removed all the code and that resolved the issue.  Whomever had placed the code in the webpart had a spit ton of MSO font code in it.

I do not know if there is a character limit in webparts or the code in the CEWP caused the crash as it was unreadable.